# alert something inside ajax file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to display a gantt chart using ajax. my gantt chart is drawn using js. I want to make dynamic, but js doesnt seem to be working. I tried this simple thing, but its not showing any alert pop up. can anyone help me find out why? here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "ajax_alert_smthing.php",
                    data:{                      
                      action:"alert"  
                    },                                 
              });              

            });
```

and my ajax file is something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alert("hi")

</script>
```

but i can't see any alert :(

Comment: Add a quote before `ajax_alert...`.

Comment: ouh yeah, sorry for that, but the quote is there, typo

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. You never add new content to the DOM.

Comment: Another thing: that code would probably break in Internet Explorer because of the extra `,` after `data:{                      
                      action:"alert"  
                    }`

Comment: what i am trying to do is to draw the whole gantt chart using js in the ajax file. but for now, just trying to get the alert work in the ajax file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `success` property on the object you pass to `$.ajax`, so this code will make an HTTP request for your HTML fragment, and then do nothing with the response.

If you really, really want to just load a JS fragment, then:

1. Make sure you are sending an `application/javascript` content-type
2. Remove the HTML from the script (and just have the script itself)
3. Use [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

But if you want to fetch some data from the server and use it to modify the page then:

1. Have the server return actual data, preferably expressed as [JSON](http://json.org)
2. Have the functions you need to modify the page based on that data in the page already
3. Have a `success` method which will call those functions using the received data as arguments

You should probably look at the [jQuery tutorials page](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) which has a large section on Ajax.

Comment: well, the success function will basically do nothing. i want the jquery to send all the variables to the ajax file and from the ajax file, use those variables, generate the whole gantt chart and alert the gantt chart. the whole chart is drawn in js.

Comment: btw, what do u mean by remove the html from the script?

Comment: @user1021350: You need to add the javascript to the page. It is client side.

Comment: "well, the success function will basically do nothing" — Stop. You're doing it wrong. The JS to draw the chart should be on the page already. It should just make use of data returned via Ajax.

Comment: "remove the html from the script" — This is HTML: `<script>`